# Why Does This Auto-Vectorizer Care About Constructors/Destructors?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vectorization

Here is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
class Vec final {
    public:
        float data[4];

        inline Vec(void) {}
        inline ~Vec(void) {}
};
Vec operator*(float const& scalar, Vec const& vec) {
    Vec result;
    #if 1
        for (int k=0;k<4;++k) result.data[k]=scalar*vec.data[k];
    #else
        float const*__restrict src =    vec.data;
        float      *__restrict dst = result.data;
        for (int k=0;k<4;++k) dst[k]=scalar*src[k];
    #endif
    return result;
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[]) {
    Vec vec;
    Vec scaledf = 2.0f * vec;
    return 0;
}
```

---

When compiling, MSVC 2013 informs me (`/Qvec-report:2`) that

> main.cpp(11) : info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1200'

This means that the "[l]oop contains loop-carried data dependences".

**I have noticed that commenting either the constructor or the destructor for `Vec` (edit: or defaulting them, e.g. `Vec()=default;`) causes it to vectorize successfully.  My question: why?**

---

Note: Toggling the `#if` will also make it work.  The `__restrict` is important.
Note: Changing `float const& scalar` to `float const scalar` causes the vectorization to report `1303` (vectorization wouldn't be a win), I suspect because the reference can be passed directly into an SSE register while the pass-by-value needs another copy.

Comment: What happens if you default (`Vec() = default;`) the constructor and destructor instead? The way you have them defined right now makes them non-trivial, maybe the optimizer doesn't like that for some reason.

Comment: @Praetorian Defaulting at least one of them causes the vectorization to succeed.

Comment: Looks (to me) like if the code for the target type is sufficiently complex, it isn't quite "smart" enough to ensure that you don't have aliasing (i.e., it can't prove that `src` and `dst` necessarily refer to distinct objects).

Comment: Cautious back-end guys do ignore the *const* keyword.  Write this in the "normal" form and pass the 1st argument as `const float scalar` instead of passing it by reference.   So it can completely dismiss the possibility that *scalar* is an element in the float[].

Comment: What happens if you add the `noexcept` qualifier to the ctor/dtor (as the `= default` version does)

Comment: @kfsone `inline Vec(void) noexcept {}` produces `error C3646: 'noexcept' : unknown override specifier`. MSVC 2013 does not support `noexcept`.

Comment: @imallett Tried in vs2015, with/without noexcept... I get `1>  c:\users\osmith\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(11) : info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1303'` which is too few iterations, but if I use your `#else` code, it vectorizes...

Comment: In 2015, if I increase the size of data[] to 16, then it vectorizes your primary case, so chances are it's a defect in 2013.

Comment: I cannot get this loop to be not vectorized using

/MP /GS- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /Ox /Ob2 /Fd"x64\Release\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_LIB" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /GF /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy /Oi /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Ot /Fp"x64\Release\test_vectorizer.pch"

Comment: @imallett Did you try vectorizing it by _mm_cvtepu8_epi32 ?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you declare an empty non virtual destructor `inline ~Vec(void) {}` with an empty default constructor `inline Vec(void) {}`?

As a result the compiler does not generate default copy constructor. Thus the code `return result;` can't be compiled without it because this requires to copy result into a temporary returned object (that is may not what you want).

Either define a copy constructor, or don't define the empty constructor and destructor at all.

Comment: The empty constructor/destructor are because of the toyness of this toy example. Also, it must be generating a copy constructor since it compiles fine. In any case, adding `inline Vec(Vec const& other) = default;` appears to have no effect.